# Issues with page fullscreen backgrounds when loading page in a new tab (not in focus)

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

Couldn't really work out what to search for to find a solution to this issue so apologies if it's a duplicate.

I've got an issue where my fullscreen background banner doesn't load property if the page is allowed to load in a browser tab that isn't in focus. It's appears to only happen in Google Chrome.

The end result is that the background image is the size of the viewport, but doesn't cover the whole document - i.e. it leaves a white gap at the bottom.

I tried to setup a fiddle, but it doesn't really replicate the issue due to it not happening in a frame, the site is a local staging env so unfortunately I don't have a link to share.

UPDATE:

After playing some more, it would appear that the CSS needs a refresh to fix the issue. Basically if I make any change to the CSS of the container it will automatically fix the white space. However, if I add new CSS to an element inline that DOES NOT fix the issue. Modifying the CSS in any way with javascript also doesn't cause it to fix.

I wonder if there's some kind of callback I can issue if the page is switched to from a different tab?

Comment: have you tried hard refreshing your browser?

Comment: That will fix the problem at my end, but that won't really solve the problem for my users. If the user opens a couple pages in new tabs while browsing the site and then switches between them they'll get the broken looking page, which I want to prevent.

Comment: Adding -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); to the fullscreen container fixed the problem but this feels like a massive hack rather than the solution.